# How to do double Wedge Product

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, exterior-algebra

I've come across this problem asking to do a double wedge product, and my professor didn't cover it.

It asks me to find the coordinates of the wedge product of *a*∧*b*∧*c*

$a = [8,-6,7,8],
b = [9,-3,8,4],
c = [4,6,5,-5]$

I would've thought, on intuition, that the solution would be $(a∧b)∧(b∧c)$. That gives something along the lines of $15$ coordinates, and I know, from the input interface, that the answer has $4$ coordinates.

The answer having $4$ coordinates confused me, considering $a∧b$ alone gives a $6$-coordinate output.

Hope you can help!

Comment: The number of coordinates relative to a basis is the dimension of the exterior power in which the wedge product lies. That dimension is $\binom{4}{k}$ for the power $k$.

Answer (score 1):

The exterior product of $n-1$ vectors of dimension $n$ is a generalization of the cross product in dimension three (if you identify $\Lambda^{n-1} \Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R^n$ by identifying $e_2 \wedge e_3 \wedge ... \wedge e_n \to e_1$, $e_3 \wedge e_3 \wedge ... \wedge e_1 \to e_2$ and so on, that's called [Hodge duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator))

You can compute it by generalizing the way you'd compute a cross product.

For instance you can compute the determinant of
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
e_1&e_2&e_3&e_4\\
8&−6&7&8\\
9&−3&8&4\\
4&6&5&−5
\end{pmatrix}
$$